# Write complex queries with Softlayer Object Storage Search API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I follow the content of this page: [API Operations for Search Services](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/API-Operations-Search-Services) and was able to make simple queries using cURL or a ruby client. I would like to make more complex queries with the API, for example on the non-existence of a metadata field, a combinaison of queries (AND, OR operators...).

Does someone know if this feature is available: [Openstack Swift OSMS](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/MetadataSearchAPI) with Softlayer, if yes, do you have queries examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the next link is the official implementation for the Proposed Metadata Search API on OpenStack. 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/API-Operations-Search-Services

As stated in the link, the only parameters that you can use are the next:

- q
- field
- type
- format
- recursive

These can be concatenated in the next way:

```
curl -X GET -i -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_1234567890abc" -H "X-Context: search" "https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_0987654321zyx/container-test?q.content_type=text&format=json"

Whereas:
AUTH_1234567890abc = your own value
AUTH_0987654321zyx = your own value
container-test = your own value
```

Note: These information can be obtained following the next link steps: https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis